# How do i declare a class constructor in IDL?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, idl

How is a class constructor define in IDL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't.  IDL is about interfaces, not how objects are constructed.  Clients don't need to know those details, just how to interact with such an object when it's available on the network.

Comment: Anyway, object creation is necessary. The question is that CORBA uses the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor is used to create and initialize an object. However, a constructor creates the object **locally**, that is, within the address space of the process that calls the constructor. Because of this, a constructor cannot be used to create an object in a different process, and this is the reason why you cannot define a constructor for an IDL interface.

If you want to create an object in a different (server) process, you can use the factory pattern, which invokes an operation on an existing object in the server. E.g.,

```
interface ObjectFactory {
  Object create(...);
  ...
};
```